# H1 tags and Wordpress - source code only sees one H1, but crawlers see three

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am currently working through the seo optimization of a website and am in the process of cleaning up an overuse of H1 tags.  It is a wordpress build, v4.

Already I am stuck on the first page, which has been updated to only have 1 H1 tag.
The source code reveals this to be the case as well.

However tools like screaming frog and some online crawlers continue to find 3.  The first two are the name of the company (cannot disclose) and the third is the actual H1.

Has anybody seen this before, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Without seeing an example or at least providing code, your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I suspect as much, unfortunately I cannot share the source code without stripping out too much of the content.  I was hoping though that somebody else had encountered and solved this issue before.  Google proves difficult given the search terms.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I feel silly. But the answer is at hand and might help somebody else.

As part of the restructuring of the site there is a new theme and I have been using a plugin to render it for me as an admin.  The crawlers however were seeing the old theme, and the un-necessary h1 tags it was creating.

The fault was that this particular theme was adding an H1 tag to the page logo. I do not know why, but I am happy to eliminate it in the meantime.